# maven build error: Error creating shaded jar (Access denied)

Tags: maven, uberjar

I get the following error trying to make an uberjar with maven, any ideas what might be going on?

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error creating shaded jar: C:\Projects\info\binf\target\classes (Access is denied)
```

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31330682/363573

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that target folder is in used by some other process.
Try to delete the folder manually and see if you are able to do it, if not then identify the process which is using that target folder and kill it.

After this try to do the build again.

Thanks