# Maven Shading Error: Access is Denied

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, access-denied

Now, I have already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914955/maven-build-error-error-creating-shaded-jar-access-denied), however it doesn't appear anything is using my target folder.

What's going on, is when I compile it fails and shows me this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.3:shade (default) on project FooProject: Error creating shaded jar: Failed to analyze class dependencies: C:\Users\paul_000\Documents\FooCore\target\classes (Access is denied) -> [Help 1]
```

I'm not quite sure exactly why this happens, as it doesn't happen on my normal computer.

EDIT: I forgot to mention, the jar I am shading does not exist on a repository. I just compile it locally (clean install).
As well, here's what I use to shade:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Maybe the target directory created with admin rights or is locked by another process. Using the -e switch to get the complete stacktrace will also help.

Comment: I'll check the full stacktrace, however it does not have admin rights (I am the only admin + I checked). I've restarted in safe mode to the same result, so I doubt it is a process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can face this error, if you're compiling from Eclipse with m2e plugin.

The workaround is to uncheck `Resolve Workspace artifacts` in the Maven Run Configuration.

[image]

Comment: This solves previous problem but now I have problem that workspace artifact is not resolved... How can I have resolution turned on and get m2e plugin working?

Comment: @svobol13 The workspace artifact is not resolved because it can't be found in your local repository. Right click on that workspace artifact then click `Run As` an click on `Maven install`. Your project should compile fine now.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, I wasted my whole day looking for why it was not creating war.

Comment: Thanks this helped me with an error `... target/classes (Is a Directory)`. Is there any way to solve this in a different way than disabling 'Resolve Workspace artifacts'?

Comment: @mxro Can you post a new question with all the details of your particular case? Feel free to leave the link to the new question in a comment here.

Comment: Here you go: [Question #37942689](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37942689/maven-shade-plugin-reports-error-creating-shaded-jar-target-classes-is-a-d). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and as this is the first question that shows up on google, I add my solution as an answer here.
In my case, the problem was related to the `dependencyReducedPomLocation` I've set.
I wanted to move the `dependency-reduced-pom` to the `target` folder and so I've set the property to `${project.build.directory}`.
However, this property does not expect a folder, but a file and the correct value for it would be `${project.build.directory}${file.separator}dependency-reduced-pom.xml`.
After this change everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading maven-shade-plugin to 3.4.1 version resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse Spring with the maven plugin.  I was seeing a similar error in the logs:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.3:shade (default) on project lds_ws_framework: Error creating shaded jar: C:\Users\fritchd\Documents\autoaction_archivetkitproject\target\classes (Access is denied) -> [Help 1]

I had recently updated my projects to use the maven-shade-plugin 2.3 from a different maven build process. I noticed I had a lot of artifacts from the previous process in the \target folder.  So I tried just deleting all files under the \target directory for that project.  When I reran the build, I didn't see the error.

Comment: More than likely you had a program using a file in the directory, or you had a terminal inside that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use the artifactSet option of maven-shade-plugin

For whatever reason this way Eclipse does not produce the "Access Denied" error

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I got it from google search. What solved the issue for me was to upgrade maven-shade-plugin to version 3.5.1.